# C# SQL Server Login Credentials

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

This is my first time connecting to SQL Server via C#, apologies in advance.

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server to get some information. The code I'm using is:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=server;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=DB; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30;"+
                                   "User ID=SQLUser;" + "Password= SQLPass;");
myConnection.Open();
```

However, when I try to connect, I get the error:

> Login failed for user 'Company\Personal ID'.

These are not the credentials I intended to use (sqluser & sqlpass). If anyone knows where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get rid of `Trusted_Connection=yes;`. It's ignoring the `User ID` and `Password` parameters because you're telling it to use your domain credentials.

Now, the error itself is saying that your domain user doesn't have a `Login` to the SQL Server.

Comment: Along with this you need to ensure that SQL Server is setup to handle both Windows and SQL server logins.  If the server is configured to only allow Windows logins then this will still fail.